# I am generating ipa file using xcode but its not installing the iphone device?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on a project with multiple teams located in different countries. So I want to send and ipa to another team, I'm very new working with xcode.

So I finally can generate ipa to devices that were added to diawi uses i am generating url  of devices on developer account.

Now the ipa that i generate but its not installing that api to the devices.

Comment: What kind of build do you generate? Ad-hoc or development? Could share some more details, like the error message you get? For that you could also check the device log in Xcode cmd+shift+2.

Comment: development just installing again try  it once

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to check

**1**- What iOS version your app support and what is the device version.

**2**- If development profile is used, are those devices UDID is registered for that profile.

**3**- Try creating Distribution profile and share the ipa.

If not from above case, please share the log erros.

Comment: thank you so much to give answer this answer useful to me once again thanks